# Why is Facebook Graph API Explorer not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to create an app that would require a Facebook login as well as access to the user's profile info.

Before getting to the whole technical stuff, I decided to test the Graph API explorer but it doesn't seem to work as expected (from the videos/tutorials I've seen). When I click on the Get Token (Get User Access Token) button and subsequently select the tokens of interest (email, photos, etc.), nothing happens afterward. I expected to be redirected to the Facebook authorization window but nothing happens. I simply get a blank input field. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Agkvt3HI_AdGJKT2tOMlFFelE) is a screen recording of it.

Clicking on the Get Page Access Token does work but gives me access to only the id and name. When I add other field and request for the tokens, nothing seems to work as seen in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Agkvt3HI_Ac1cxRXRBdFBFVFk/view) screen recording.

What gives?

Comment: Well Graph API is working here, you are having trouble getting an access token, which I know you are aware of. First thing I notice, maybe your adblocker is affecting things. Second thing, your page access token did not change at all when you tried to get more permissions in video 2. Check your browser console, if there are any erros plz report back.

Comment: Jesus! I'm slow. Not once did it occur to me that Adblock could have been the problem. I tried it in Chrome Incognito and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Hahha I only know because I have had the same problem in the past  

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Adblockers can affect the way Facebook's Graph API Explorer works.**

From your video, youre running an adblocker on this page. Suspend the adblocker and try again. This can create all sorts of unexpected behaviors, not least of which is aggressive popup blocking.

Comment: Yup! That pretty much was the problem. Thanks!